Emulator is not starting
Hi I downloaded Koala android and started emulator. I am getting “emulator process has terminated with exit code 134”.
I tried a few troubleshooting options like downloaded emulator again and then check disk free space. But nothing worked. Please suggest. I am using apple laptop. I also checked log. I see “Emulator: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)”
